# Simple pilist prototype pollution dependabot alert

Tags: github-actions, dependabot

I’m working on a JavaScript/typescript project and I have used the github provided code scanner CI. Until one day I found a warning popping up saying:”simple-plist v1.3.0 was discovered to contain a prototype pollution vulnerability via .parse().” I thought updating the package should fix it but github says there was not patched version. I’m just wondering should I ignore this warning or should I do something about it? Even know they said this is a critical vulnerability 9.8/10.bit

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should update simple-plist. According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-plist there is already a newer version v1.3.1

Comment: Have you checked whether the library is pulled in transitively ?